# How to extract each index from array of array list in android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> parsedPODAY_ID=new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<String> parsedPODAY_P_IMG=new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<String> parsedPODAY_NAME=new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<String> parsedPODAY_PRICE=new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<String> parsedPODAY_OFFPRICE=new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fullPoday = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fullPoday = new ArrayList<>();
fullPoday.add(parsedPODAY_ID);
fullPoday.add(parsedPODAY_NAME);
fullPoday.add(parsedPODAY_P_IMG);
fullPoday.add(parsedPODAY_PRICE);
fullPoday.add(parsedPODAY_OFFPRICE);
```

I am having array of arraylist as fullPoday.But in another activity how can i get each index of array list

Comment: you want to pass fullPoday from one activity to another ? If so you can create class FullPoday implements Serializable {
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fullPoday = new ArrayList<>();
}

and than you can pass it to Intent like this 
intent.putExtra("array", fullPoday);

and get it in next activity getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array")

Comment: yes it want to pass fullPoday to another activity

Comment: Use my solution create new class with array into it, implements Serializable and pass it thow intent extra it will work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207602/pass-serializable-object-throught-intent

Comment: Ok thanks!! @KonstantinVolkov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fullPoday.get(0).add("Test string 1");

String result = fullPoday.get(0).get(0);

Log.d("tag", result);
```

But you try manipulate with string tables. May be better to use data base mechanics.